# How to get a key in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON Object from server.

If I run

```
console.log(msg);
```

I got this from console
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN163.png)

how to get a key or all keys from Object ?
I've tried

```
console.log(msg.Object.key)
```

but complain

> Property 'Object' does not exist on type '{}'

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT:

```
listener.subscribe((msg:any) => {

      console.log((msg.data[0]));
```

this is working, and I have output

> Object {key: "IL_IMAGER", value: "2.7872460627869"}

But I only want the key

I tried :

```
console.log((msg.data[0].key));
```

but

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Problem Solved . 
It was because I have two Object in server, one of them doesn't have 'value' .

so this is will be answer :

```
  console.log((msg.data[0].key));
```

Comment: `msg.Data[0].key` - `msg` is an Object, which has a property, `data`, which is an array of objects. `Object` isn't actually a property, its just the console telling you the variable data type.

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}', should I initial Data as Data:[] ?

Comment: How is `msg` initialized?

Comment: it will be `Object.keys(msg)`

Comment: message = {};  // initial here 

listener.subscribe(msg => {
          this.message = msg;

          console.log((this.message))
        
      });

Comment: `(msg: any) => { console.log(msg.data[0]) }`

Comment: Thank you tymeJV ! it works ! just one more question , what if I only need key ?

Comment: I've tried  console.log((msg.data[0].key))   but cannot read property key of undefined

Comment: do like this for one key `msg.data[0]?.key`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screen shot you have a data like this

```js
var arr = [{"id":"X","price":"5","size":"5"},
          {"id":"Y","price":"10","size":"5"},
          {"id":"X","price":"5","size":"5"},
          {"id":"Y","price":"10","size":"5"},
          {"id":"Z","price":"5","size":"5"},
          {"id":"X","price":"5","size":"5"},
          {"id":"X","price":"5","size":"5"},
          {"id":"Z","price":"5","size":"5"},
          {"id":"Q","price":"11","size":"5"}]; 

var test = arr.map((data) => {
 return data.id;
});
console.log(test);
```

**Use in Angular like this**

```
let keys = yourArray.map((item) => {
    return item.key;
});
```